# Determine the Jordan Normal form of the Jordan block J^3 for n ≥ 9

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I have to determine the Jordan Normal form of the Jordan block J^3. Now I know that J^3 is (0,0,0,e_1,e_2,...,e_(n-3)). I also calculated that the Jordan Normal form of this block for any given n is always a matrix consisting of 3 Jordan blocks of size k/k+1 in the diagonal namely: [J(k),J(k),J(k)] when n=3*k ; [J(k+1),J(k),J(k)] when n=3*k +1 and [J(k+1),J(k+1),J(k)] when n=3*k+2. So if we write the dimension of the Jordan block n = 3k+r where k∈N, k≥3 und r∈{0,1,2}. I can determine the Jordan Normal form but I am having trouble proving why the 3 Jordan blocks are always of size k/k+1 when instead (example) for n=9 it could be J(4),J(3) and J(2) instead of all being J(3).
Does anyone have any idea how to help me. It would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Your question is difficult to read in its current form; please format it using MathJax, per the [instructions here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Also, please explain your notation. What exactly is the matrix $J$? It sounds like you're talking about the Jordan block associated with the eigenvalue zero, but please [edit] your question to explicitly state whether this is the case

Comment: @BenGrossmann Exactly J is the Jordan block with the eigenvalue 0.  As for your answer I assume it means that the size of the Jordan blocks cannot be bigger than k/k+1 but would you please elaborate more on why it is so ? Thanks!

Comment: Again, please edit your post to reflect that.

Comment: The point is that if the a matrix $A$ has the block $J(m)$ in its normal form, then $A^{m-1}$ must be non-zero

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** note that if $n = 3k + r$, then we have $(J^3)^k = 0$ if $r=0$ and $(J^3)^{k+1} = 0$ if $r = 1,2$. Consider what this tells you about the sizes of the Jordan blocks in the normal form of $J^3$.